# Programmatically Harvest and Disapprove Metadata - GeoPortal Server

Tags: python, esri-geoportal-server

Is it possible to synchronize an existing metadata catalog in esri's GeoPortal Server? I have access to the server, and have a script to add an XML file to our web accessible folder. After this script runs, I manually log in to the Geoportal site and synchronize content.

Is there any way to run this synchronization without using the web interface? Ideally it would be run in the command line on server, but I could look into (somehow) calling this from Java as well, as may be described in the [GeoPortal documentation](http://help.arcgis.com/en/geoportal_extension/10.0/sdk/). Do I need to get into [extending the web harvester](https://github.com/Esri/geoportal-server/wiki/Extending-the-Web-Harvester) or is there an easier way to do this?

Finally, is there a way to programmatically set the status of an existing record by GUID (i.e. approved/disapproved)?